# last click on increment or decrement button wiill call ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototype

i have increment button that are constantly calling ajax that are talking too much load time.

```
<div id="topproqty890" class="product-qty qty_cover">
    <div style=" display:none;" id="myContenttop890" class="outer">
       <input type="number" pattern="[0-9.]+" id="topproqtyinput890" value="18" min="0" name="tex" class="input">
       <input type="button" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('topproqtyinput890');
         qty_div = document.getElementById('topproqtydiv890');

          if(!qty_el.value || qty_el.value &lt; 0)
             { 
             return false;
            }
           qty_div.innerHTML=qty_el.value;
           document.getElementById('myContenttop890').style.display='none';
           return addtocartcusmtom(890,'top');" value="ok" name="button" class="button">
           <div class="arow"><img alt="" src="http://10.10.10.77/nemlig/skin/frontend/default/nemlig/images/arow_qty.jpg"></div>
            </div>
               <div onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('topproqtyinput890');
                 qty_div = document.getElementById('topproqtydiv890'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) &amp;&amp; qty &gt; 0 ) qty_el.value--;
                                        qty_div.innerHTML=qty_el.value;return addtocartcusmtom(890,'top');" class="left_b"> - </div>
              <div onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('topproqtyinput890');
                                        qty_div = document.getElementById('topproqtydiv890');
               var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) qty_el.value++;
                                         qty_div.innerHTML=qty_el.value;return addtocartcusmtom(890,'top');" class="right_b"> + </div>
                <div onclick="javascript:toggleDiv('myContenttop890');" id="topproqtydiv890" class="input">42</div>
                </div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qaisarsatti/gy5zovwm/)

my ajax code

```
function addtocartcusmtom(pro_id,prefix)
    {

       var qty =$(prefix+'proqtyinput'+pro_id).getValue();
       if(!qty || qty < 0)
         { 
         return false;
         }




       var url="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('cartupdater') ?>";

       cartajax =new Ajax.Request(url, {
              method: 'post',   
              parameters: {qty: qty, product: pro_id},
              onFailure: function(response){
    cartajax=undefined;
        return false;
    },


    onSuccess: function(response)
    { 


          response = response.responseText.evalJSON(true); 


        return false;







    }
          }); 
    }
```

Comment: also share your ajax code, and what you want to do? and what problem you are facing ?

Comment: @Qazi it is constantly calling the ajax on every increment or decrement that are taking so much time.   `addtocartcusmtom(890,'top');` this is the function

Comment: why are you returning the value here `return addtocartcusmtom(890,'top');`? what is your ajax method doing? why is it taking time?

Comment: adding product into cart increase or decrease the quantity..

Comment: avoid to use ajax call on inc/decrement buttons. inc/decrement and add a button `save quantity` which will trigger your ajax request to save quantity

Comment: @Qazi i cannot do on that i have to call ajax on increment/ decrement for quantity update...

Comment: can you share your ajax code ?

Comment: @Qazi added the ajax code too

Comment: your method is quite fine, you have to change your scenario, don't call your ajax method on inc/decrements button, reason why. eg a user added 3 items in cart and for 3 items it randomly click on inc/decrement 10 times(each, in a single minute) now `3 * 10 = 30` ajax req sending to server.  similarly there are 10 people more  which do same thing eg `30 * 10 = 300` now look 300 request in a minute cause much burden on server. it will cause laziness. So I am Suggesting this technique. look [here](http://cdn.dick-blick.com/images/customerservice/howto/UpdateQty.jpg)

Comment: @Qazi i know this technique but this is client requirement so i have to stick with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105002/discussion-between-qazi-and-qaisar-satti).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Suggestion are,

your method is quite fine, you have to change your scenario, don't call your ajax method on inc/decrements button, reason why.

eg a user added `3 items` in cart and for `3 items` it randomly click on inc/decrement `10 times(each, in a single minute)` now `3 * 10 = 30` ajax req sending to server. similarly there are 10 people more which do same thing eg `30 * 10 = 300` now look `300` request in a minute cause much burden on server. it will cause laziness.

So I am Suggesting this technique. look [here](http://cdn.dick-blick.com/images/customerservice/howto/UpdateQty.jpg)